# What's a generic way of using ddply/plyr to average values of a repeated row for each column in a data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

Let's say I have a data frame like the following:

```
Name   A1   A2   A3   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3
100     3    6    2    9    2    2    1    5    1
200     5    3    7    3    2    6    3    8    3
200     5    5    9    5    0    4    5    4    1
300     4    8    2    7    0    2    1    4    9
```

The item named `200` is duplicated. I want to average out the values for each column for these two `200` rows, so I only have unique items represented in the rows:

```
Name   A1   A2   A3   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3
100     3    6    2    9    2    2    1    5    1
200     5    4    8    4    1    5    4    6    2
300     4    8    2    7    0    2    1    4    9
```

My novice R coding skills lead me to use the following:

`removed.duplicates<-ddply(df,"Name",summarize,A1=mean(A1),A2=mean(A2),A3=mean(A3),B1=mean(B1),B2=mean(B2),B3=mean(B3),C1=mean(C1),C2=mean(C2),C3=mean(C3))`

This works just fine, but I have many more tables that are similar, but might have dropped samples (no A2, B3, for example) that need to be processed. How can I rewrite this so that I can apply it generically to average duplicated row names for each column, regardless of how many columns there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a rather obscure search for understanding how `%` works in R, I came across the basic function `aggregate()`, which works quite simply.

`removed.duplicates<-aggregate(df,by=list(Name),FUN=mean)`

This gave me the desired results, although with an extra column:

```
Group.1   Name   A1   A2   A3   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3
100        100    3    6    2    9    2    2    1    5    1
200        200    5    4    8    4    1    5    4    6    2
300        300    4    8    2    7    0    2    1    4    9
```

It's easy enough to get rid of that column, though.

Comment: Hi. I should have mentioned that the % operator is used to create infix functions like %>% in my example above using dplyr. The %>% operator was introduced in the magrittr package and can be used in a wide variety of setting to string operations together. Here is a link specifically to the magrittr vignitte page with lots of examples of it in use outside of dplyr...http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html -- cheers

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. I put your example in a data.frame called df.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused... what does `%>%` mean?

Answer (score 1):

Using base R on a more complex data:

```
> ddf
  Name A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
1  100  3  6  2  9  2  2  1  5  1
2  200  5  3  7  3  2  6  3  8  3
3  200  5  5  9  5  0  4  5  4  1
4  300  4  8  2  7  0  2  1  4  9
5  300  2  4  2  9  6  6  5  8  1
6  300  3  6  2  5  8  8  6  6  5
7  500  4  8  2  7  0  2  1  4  9
> 
> ddf = structure(list(Name = c(100L, 200L, 200L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 500L
+ ), A1 = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), A2 = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
+ 4L, 6L, 8L), A3 = c(2L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), B1 = c(9L, 3L, 
+ 5L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 7L), B2 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 0L), B3 = c(2L, 
+ 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 2L), C1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L), 
+     C2 = c(5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L), C3 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 
+     1L, 5L, 9L)), .Names = c("Name", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", 
+ "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
+ -7L))
> 
> dups = ddf[duplicated(ddf$Name),]$Name
> ddf2 = ddf[!ddf$Name %in% dups,]
> for(nn in unique(dups))  ddf2 = rbind(ddf2, colMeans(ddf[ddf$Name==nn,]))
> ddf2
  Name A1 A2 A3 B1       B2       B3 C1 C2 C3
1  100  3  6  2  9 2.000000 2.000000  1  5  1
7  500  4  8  2  7 0.000000 2.000000  1  4  9
3  200  5  4  8  4 1.000000 5.000000  4  6  2
4  300  3  6  2  7 4.666667 5.333333  4  6  5
```